# Filtering in angular 14 for the array of values in single column

Tags: angular, filtering, angular-material-table, angular-event-emitter

How can I filter a single column values from a material table  ?

```
FilterChange(event:Event)
{  
const fillvalue=(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;  
this.dataSource.filter = fillvalue;
}
```

This is my function, I need to call the function when the text is entered and click the search button in the form, I'm using <mat-form-field> for the input. Here event is the value passed after the text is entered in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter predicate to create your own custom filter function

```js
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (
  data: PeriodicElement,
  filter: string
): boolean =>
  data.weight.toString().indexOf(filter) === -1 ? false : true;
```

here, weight is the column name

Comment: Thank you for your help,   But unfortunately this didn't solved my current problem.

Comment: Is FilterChange method not getting called?

Comment: Ya it is being called in the button click